# How to disable color swatches in magento

Tags: magento, colors, e-commerce

I want to remove "search by color" in product list of my website, how to do that?

Comment: Maybe go to your magento backend and switch to "catalog" -> "attribute" -> "manage attributes". choose the attribute `color` and disable the function `searchable` at the attribute detail setting page.

Answer (score 1):

Go into: **Catalog/Attributes/Manage Attribute Sets**

Select "**Color**"

In the frontend properties section you can specify where you want the color option to appear.

In your case you want to disable "**Use in Search Results Layered Navigation**" and "**Use in Layered Navigation**"